# Change HighCharts plotLine-value and -label

Tags: highcharts

I have implemented a plot line that's showing an average of all values:

```
"yAxis": {
  plotLines: [{
     color: 'red',
     value: 22, 
     width: '1',
     label: {
        text: 'Average: 22'
     }
  }]
},
```

I want to change the average-value on legendItemClick. Is it possible to change some plotLine-properties programatically?

What I tried so far is this:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
     events: {
        legendItemClick: function (event) {
           var average = 15;
           event.target.chart.userOptions.yAxis.plotLines[0].value = average;
           event.target.chart.userOptions.yAxis.plotLines[0].label.text = 'Average: ' + average;
        }
     },
  }
},
```

The value and the label-text aren't changing in the chart. Also I tried to [redraw the chart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.redraw) but it still isn't changing the plot line. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have found an acceptable answer to my own question:

```
var average = 15;
event.target.chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('average');
event.target.chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
  id: 'average',
  color: 'red',
  width: 1,
  value: average,
  zIndex: 200,
  label: {
     text: 'Average: ' + average
  }
});
```

I have to specify an ID for the plotLine, destroy it and create a new one.